# Why do posts not escape HTML characters?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was re-reading on of [my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493383/641833) when I noticed that some of it was missing.  Specifically anything which was not in a code block which started with a less then symbol.  Replacing the sysmbol with an &lt; fixed the issue, but why does SO not do this replacement by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why does SO not do this replacement by default?

Because Stack Exchange also allows a small subset of HTML. Escaping all HTML characters would display HTML code as text, which is undesired.

Comment: Really? What HTML do they allow that isn't covered by the included formatting features?

Comment: @Trisped: Striked out text, for example, is only possible using HTML.

Comment: <kbd>as well</kbd>